# bootstrap modal not popping out for rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed the bootstrap in my rails 6. this is my javascript>packs>application.js

```
import 'bootstrap'
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")
```

in my config> webpack>environment.js, this is my setup

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const webpack = require("webpack")

environment.plugins.append("Provide", new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
    })
)

module.exports = environment
```

I tried to use the default modal in my index.html.erb

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, nothing appears when I click on the modal. Is there something I am missing out?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to change the place of **import 'bootstrap** means place this line after require jquery then try.

Comment: tried... didnt work